# How to make html table using foreach with fix first column?

Tags: php, html, laravel, foreach, html-table

```
<table>

    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>
    <colgroup></colgroup>

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
            @foreach($cloud as $cu)
            <th>
                <h2>{{$cu->name}}</h2><br>
                <h3 style="font-size: 35px;"><sup class="price-sign">$</sup>{{$cu->price}}<span style="font-size: large;">/{{trans('file.month')}}</span></h3>
                <p>{{$cu->description}}</p>
            </th>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tfoot>

        <tr>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
             @foreach($cloud as $cu)
            <td>
            <a href="/deatalis/{{$cu->id}}" style="text-decoration: none;" >More Details
            </a>



            </td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>

    </tfoot>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th><i class="icon-user"></i>
            Members Number 
            <span>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</span>
            </th>
            @foreach($cloud as $cu)
            <td>{{$cu->users}}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><i class="icon-drawer"></i>
            Storage 
            <span>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</span>
            </th>
            @foreach($cloud as $cu)
            <td>{{$cu->space}}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th><i class="icon-layers"></i>
            Backups 
            <span>Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor.</span>
            </th>
            @foreach($cloud as $cu)
            <td>{{$cu->backup}}</td>
            @endforeach
        </tr>

    </tbody>

</table>
```

I want to make this table :
in this case, I make foreach for every row include the first column title plus the for each for the same row and the same for every form!
This is not useful when I make a form for all table to send parameter!

[image]

**So I want to make the first column fixed and then make it with one foreach** 
Any Help!
thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you are iterating through an array or object to generate a dynamic table, it's better define theads ahead(in a static way).